# Laravel Middleware is not work properly for Check Permission

Tags: php, laravel

I'm developing a Laravel `ACL` System. In my `ACL` I'm grant the permissions via `HasPermission` Middleware, in my middleware can't check any permission it's always  executed the `redirect()->back()` method.

Here is my code Sample.

```
class HasPermission
{

public function handle($request, Closure $next,...$permissions)
{
    // $permissions = explode(',', $permissions);
    //dd($permissions);

    foreach($permissions as $permission){
        if (Auth::user()->can($permission)) {
            return $next($request);
        }
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}
}
```

My Controller.

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->middleware('HasPermission:Role-Read,Role-Delete')->only('userEdit');
    $this->middleware('can:Role-Update')->only('userEdit');
}
```

This. `Auth::user()->can($permission)` is not work properly. What will be the solutions for this problems.

Comment: What does your policy look like?

Answer (score 0):

try:
Auth::user()->can('field you want to update',$permission);